# What would be a realistic way to lever a pallet bed?

Tags: wood, bedroom

I'm planning to build a pallet bed base, like [this one](https://echosverts.com/2016/10/23/diy-lit-double-et-tables-de-chevet-integrees-en-palettes/) or [this one](https://zazamoukproduction.wordpress.com/creation/lit-en-palette/).

The main problem everyone state about pallet bed bases is the dust that gather beneath.

Thus, I would like to engineer a way to lever the entire bedbase+mattress about 20-30cm, so we can clean the dust easily.

The mattress is queen-size (160cm x 200cm) and should wheight approximatively 32.5kg. I planned to use 4 pallets for the bed base, and maybe 1 or 2 for the bed frame, which are not supposed to move.

I thought about some lever or some pulley, but since I'm no enginneer, I have no clue how to calculate distances and forces.

I can manage calculus, I just need indications about which formulas I should consider and which material/technic/etc would be best.

If argued well, I can consider the "you cannot do it" answer, but I hope I can.

Comment: A pallet bed is, by definition, a loosely-coupled set of individual components (the pallets). It's going to be difficult to lift something like that without rigidly combining the parts. Why can't it be disassembled once or twice a year for cleaning?

Comment: Why not just build a better design that doesn't allow dust to accumulate (eg, no open spaces)? Anything involving pulleys, lifts, or even making 4 pallets into a single rigid structure is going be *way* more complicated, probably take longer to build, and still not be as good. Even if you manage to build something that only takes 15 minutes to disassemble/lift the bed to clean and then put back, and you do it 3 times a year, that's still more time than *never* having to clean under the bed.

Comment: Or put legs on the pallets so its sits high enough off the floor that your vacuum can fit underneath. Put a piece of 4x4 under each corner (so the pallet is sitting on top), and attach it with metal brackets. Even better is to notch the 4x4 so it supports the pallet but has a piece sticking up to screw into, like this: https://i.imgur.com/PZdVkCh.png

Comment: I think that disassembling the bed to clean it is very annoying. Also, the mattress need to breath so I cannot make the bed fully air-proof.

Comment: Hmm yeah putting legs on my pallets could do the trick !

Comment: I was going to suggest cleaning with a leaf blower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not attempt to lift it. The moving it to one side - vacuum, move it back the other way - vacuum.. method works better. (Though you may have a thin dust strip in the middle if you don't have enough room to roll it over far enough.)

You could add some casters to the pallets so you can move the whole thing around a bit but that could get expensive.

Your cheapest solution is probably to go out and buy a bedframe.

[image: Adjustable bed frame.]

That will also make it a lot easier to "make the bed".

Comment: You can get these bed frames at your local restore or goodwill for $10-15.

Comment: The problem is that there won't be enough room for the bed to move. But I'll check about the bedframe, it seems interesting thanks

Comment: @DanChaltiel, remember you only need to be able to move the bed about 100cm in each direction.

Comment: I think I'll have 20-30cm on each side max :s

Comment: OH.. that is tight then...In that case I'd box it in so you don't have to worry about it. @DanChaltiel

Answer (score 0):

Don't use pallets.  **Use skids.**

A skid is a pallet with stronger top boards, broader feet, and no annoying bottom boards that are hard to clean around. They are tall enough for a forklift to get under, and should be tall enough for a Roomba to get under.

The bigger problem is that pallet-wood is *really cheap wood*.  It's very rough cut with lots of saw chafe and snags, all of which collect dust voraciously.  It is hardwood, so you think "finish it like hardwood", but it won't work like hardwood, it tears easily and has too many voids.  You can't imagine wood could be this bad.

Comment: I'd also be concerned about getting NEW pallets. You really do not want to bring any mold or who knows what chemical into your sleeping quarters.